# XSLT and XSLFO namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces, xsl-fo

I have the following issue with XSL namespaces. I produce a PDF using FOP with one XSL file  and one XML file.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding= "ISO-8859-2"?>
<ReportContent>BLABLA<yt:picture src="pic.png"/></ReportContent>
```

Here is my XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:yt="http://www.yt.com/text/2"
   >
<xsl:template match="/"> 
<fo:root >
[...]
<fo:flow >
      <fo:block> <xsl:apply-templates select='ReportContent'> </xsl:apply-templates></fo:block>
 </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to include the namespace yt:. When I do it in the xml like this:

```
 <?xml version= "1.0" encoding= "ISO-8859-2"?>
    <ReportContent       xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:yt="http://www.yt.com/text/2">
BLABLA<yt:picture src="pic.png"/>
</ReportContent>
```

It works perfectly.

But in real life I cannot add namespace to my xml (the way the xml is created doesn't allow it).

So I tried to write it only on the xsl but it doesn't work at all .(I tried to add it to every tag in the xsl and it doesn't work).

I don't understand how this whole namespace thing works...

Can you help me find where to put the namespace in the xsl so I don't get any error.

Hope my question is clear

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The XML document you have is not well-formed XML, with regard to namespaces: it uses the `yt:` prefix without declaring it. So it's not XSLT's fault that it can't process the XML file successfully. What are you using to create that XML file that allows use of namespace prefixes but doesn't allow you to create them?

Comment: By "create them" I meant "declare them".

Comment: If I understand well, if xml uses the namespace yt:, the declaration has to be in the xml and it cannot be otherwise ?

Comment: Actually I'm using a program that generate xml but this program is a "black box". If I really have to write the declaration in the xml I can do it but it will take much more time for me to change the xml than to change the xsl.

Comment: As you mention not understanding how this whole namespace thing works... My experience has been that XML namespaces are an area where a solid understanding really pays off. (Translation: a weak understanding leads to unending, painful struggles.) It's worth putting some time into learning how namespaces work. You can pick your preferred tutorial; here are a couple that look good: http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm, http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html

Comment: okay thanks a lot. I will read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ricky, yes, the XML has to be changed. Sorry. It should look something like this:

```
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding= "ISO-8859-2"?>
<ReportContent xmlns:yt="http://www.yt.com/text/2">BLABLA<yt:picture src="pic.png"/>
</ReportContent>
```